# Typo in homework question?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this possible?

[image]

The row operation that forms the elementary matrix must be of the form of replacing a row by itself added to the multiple of another row, and this can't be done.

Comment: Subtract the 3rd row from the 2nd one

Comment: wow im stupid thanks

Comment: can you make that an answer so I can give you the cred:)

Comment: simply accept Siong’s answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a typo.

Use the third row to eliminate the $(2,1)$ entry. $R_2-R_3$ rather than focusing on the first two rows.

Comment: So, the elementary matrix looks like $ \left( \begin{array}{c c c}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & x \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $